# What's the simplest algorithm to escape a single character?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, escaping

I'm trying to write two functions `escape(text, delimiter)` and `unescape(text, delimiter)` with the following properties:

1. The result of `escape` does not contain `delimiter`.
2. `unescape` is the reverse of `escape`, i.e.

   ```
   unescape(escape(text, delimiter), delimiter) == text
   ```

   for all values of `text` and `delimiter`

It is OK to restrict the allowed values of `delimiter`.

---

**Background**: I want to create a delimiter-separated string of values. To be able to extract the same list out of the string again, I must ensure that the individual, separated strings do not contain the separator.

---

**What I've tried**: I came up with a simple solution (pseudo-code):

```
escape(text, delimiter):   return text.Replace("\", "\\").Replace(delimiter, "\d")
unescape(text, delimiter): return text.Replace("\d", delimiter).Replace("\\", "\")
```

but discovered that property 2 failed on the test string `"\d<delimiter>"`. Currently, I have the following working solution

```
escape(text, delimiter):   return text.Replace("\", "\b").Replace(delimiter, "\d")
unescape(text, delimiter): return text.Replace("\d", delimiter).Replace("\b", "\")
```

which seems to work, as long as `delimiter` is not `\`, `b` or `d` (which is fine, I don't want to use those as delimiters anyway). However, since I have not formally proven its correctness, I'm afraid that I have missed some case where one of the properties is violated. Since this is such a common problem, I assume that there is already a "well-known proven-correct" algorithm for this, hence my question (see title).

Comment: Escaping?  Reliable, simple and fast?  Lol.

Comment: What's the problem with reliable, simple and fast escaping?

Comment: @user1228 No need to lol on everything

Answer (score 5):

Your first algorithm is correct.

The error is in the implementation of unescape(): you need to replace both `\d` by `delimiter` and `\\` by `\`, **in the same pass**.
You can't use several calls to Replace() like this.

Here's some sample C# code for safe quoting of delimiter-separated strings:

```
    static string QuoteSeparator(string str,
        char separator, char quoteChar, char otherChar) // "~" -> "~~"     ";" -> "~s"
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if (c == quoteChar)
            {
                sb.Append(quoteChar);
                sb.Append(quoteChar);
            }
            else if (c == separator)
            {
                sb.Append(quoteChar);
                sb.Append(otherChar);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString(); // no separator in the result -> Join/Split is safe
    }
    static string UnquoteSeparator(string str,
        char separator, char quoteChar, char otherChar) // "~~" -> "~"     "~s" -> ";"
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        bool isQuoted = false;
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if (isQuoted)
            {
                if (c == otherChar)
                    sb.Append(separator);
                else
                    sb.Append(c);
                isQuoted = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (c == quoteChar)
                    isQuoted = true;
                else
                    sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        if (isQuoted)
            throw new ArgumentException("input string is not correctly quoted");
        return sb.ToString(); // ";" are restored
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encodes the given strings as a single string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The strings.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The separator.</param>
    /// <param name="quoteChar">The quote char.</param>
    /// <param name="otherChar">The other char.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string QuoteAndJoin(this IEnumerable<string> input,
        char separator = ';', char quoteChar = '~', char otherChar = 's')
    {
        CommonHelper.CheckNullReference(input, "input");
        if (separator == quoteChar || quoteChar == otherChar || separator == otherChar)
            throw new ArgumentException("cannot quote: ambiguous format");
        return string.Join(new string(separator, 1), (from str in input select QuoteSeparator(str, separator, quoteChar, otherChar)).ToArray());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decodes the strings encoded in a single string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encoded">The encoded.</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The separator.</param>
    /// <param name="quoteChar">The quote char.</param>
    /// <param name="otherChar">The other char.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAndUnquote(this string encoded,
        char separator = ';', char quoteChar = '~', char otherChar = 's')
    {
        CommonHelper.CheckNullReference(encoded, "encoded");
        if (separator == quoteChar || quoteChar == otherChar || separator == otherChar)
            throw new ArgumentException("cannot unquote: ambiguous format");
        return from s in encoded.Split(separator) select UnquoteSeparator(s, separator, quoteChar, otherChar);
    }
```

Comment: Note that if he replaced the delimiter with \<delimiter> instead of \d, the algorithm would work as-is, even with multiple passes..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have an alternative replacement for the case when the delimiter *does* start with `\`, `b` or `d`.  Use the same alternative replacement in the `unescape` algorithm as well